# PostgreSQL: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

When I press execute button, sometimes it is OK, and then I roll back and press execute button again and again, after have been made about 5 times, it show the error message:

> This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to
>   internal error

My query is as follows:

```
WITH HyperGroup AS (
   select
      'Group Type' ::text AS mm_type
      ,'Group Name' ::text AS mm_group
), number1 AS (
   SELECT
      SUM(fl.flower1 +  fl.flower2 + fl.flower3 - fl.flower4) AS season
      ,'Group Type' ::text AS mm_type
      ,'Group Name' ::text AS mm_group
   FROM (x_flwr1 as fl INNER JOIN x_flwr2 as grass
   ON REPLACE(fl.flower5, ' ', '') = grass.flower6
   AND TO_DATE(fl.flower7, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= TO_DATE(CONCAT(grass.flower8, grass.flower9), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
   AND fl.flower7 = (
      SELECT MIN(fl2.flower7) FROM x_flwr1 as fl2
      WHERE TO_DATE(fl.flower7, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= TO_DATE(CONCAT(grass.flower8, grass.flower9), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
      AND  REPLACE(fl.flower5, ' ', '') = grass.flower6
      )
   )
   WHERE
      fl.flower10 != 'Flower10 Value'
   AND fl.flower10 NOT LIKE 'M%'
   AND fl.flower11 != 'Flower11 Value'
   AND fl.flower12 != 0
   AND fl.flower3 > 0
), number2 AS (
      SELECT
         SUM(fl.flower3 - fl.flower4) AS season
         ,'Group Type' ::text AS mm_type
         ,'Group Name' ::text AS mm_group
      FROM (x_flwr1 as fl INNER JOIN x_flwr2 as grass
      ON REPLACE(fl.flower5, ' ', '') = grass.flower6
      AND TO_DATE(fl.flower7, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= TO_DATE(CONCAT(grass.flower8, grass.flower9), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
      AND fl.flower7 = (
         SELECT MIN(fl2.flower7) FROM x_flwr1 as fl2
         WHERE TO_DATE(fl.flower7, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= TO_DATE(CONCAT(grass.flower8, grass.flower9), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
         AND  REPLACE(fl.flower5, ' ', '') = grass.flower6
      ))
      WHERE
          fl.flower10 != 'Flower10 Value'
      AND fl.flower10 NOT LIKE 'M%'
      AND fl.flower11 != 'Flower11 Value'
      AND fl.flower12 != 0
      AND fl.flower3 > 0
)
SELECT
   count(*)
FROM
 ((HyperGroup LEFT OUTER JOIN number1 ON HyperGroup.mm_type = number1.mm_type AND HyperGroup.mm_group = number1.mm_group)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN number2 ON HyperGroup.mm_type = number2.mm_type AND HyperGroup.mm_group = number2.mm_group)
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: In what environment do you "press execute button" and what does "roll back" mean? And why do you do this repeatedly?

Comment: Please add the exact version. Google suggests it's Redshift not PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please add the output of `select version()`

Comment: I use sqlworkbenchj/amazon redshift and I press roll back button after edited query and then press execute button again to get result.If I  don't press roll back button after edited, it happened error.I do execute repeatedly because of executing the query about 4 or 5 times is OK, or sometimes is OK and sometimes show the error:This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error                                                                                                              Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: Actually, I want to say is  I use sqlworkbenchj & amazon redshift.
I edit the query and execute again but error will still happen without doing rollback. 
But if I roll back and execute again the error will no longer appear 
and then appear again  after continuously pressing execute button.

Execute repeatedly because of the query has bug &
usually execution about 4 or 5 times  and then error will occur

Error message is 
“This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error"

Comment: select version().....PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.960